# PHP Xpath Result always null

Tags: php, xpath

Here is my code, i wanna find out the URL of this image.
Its a site, which generate a random image so i wanna grab the image always from this xPath

`xPath = /html/body/section[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/img`

Here my Code:

```
$url    = "http://www.funcloud.com/random";
$result = (string) reset(simplexml_import_dom(DOMDocument::loadHTML($url))->xpath("//html/body/section[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/img@src"));

if($result == null)
 echo 'result is null';
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you debug it:

```
<?php
$url    = "http://www.funcloud.com/random";
$parts = array(
    'body',
    'section[3]',
    'div',
    'article',
    'div',
    'div[2]',
    'div',
    'div[2]',
    'div',
    'div',
    'a',
    'img',
);
$document = simplexml_import_dom(DOMDocument::loadHTML($url));
$xpath = '//html';
$previous_result = array();
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    $xpath .= '/' . $part;
    $result = $document->xpath($xpath);
    if( ! count($result) )
    {
        echo('No content for: ' . $xpath . PHP_EOL);
        break;
    }
    $previous_result = $result;
}

echo('Last good result: ' . PHP_EOL);
var_dump($previous_result);
```

This gives me:

```
No content for: //html/body/section[3]
Last good result: 
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#1 (1) {
    public $p =>
    string(30) "http://www.funcloud.com/random"
  }
}
```

Looks like you need to adjust your xpath.

**Edit**:
Actually looks like the service has been discontinued:

```
% curl -D /dev/stdout -o /dev/null -s http://www.funcloud.com/random
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Mon, 11 Aug 2014 10:04:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u12
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1t636677vk8uor7d6vfo3n4c91; path=/; domain=.funcloud.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://funcloud.com/
```